# Sqoop ORACLE SSL JDBC network adapter could not establish the connection using TCPS protocol

Tags: oracle, ssl, jdbc, sqlplus, sqoop

Am trying to import(SQOOP) table data from ORACLE DB to HDFS using SSL connection.

Sqoop command i use is as below,

> sqoop import -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/Wallets/client_wallet/ewallet.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=WalletPasswd123 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@testssl --username test --password test --table APP_INSTANCE

ERROR:

```
17/06/30 18:43:12 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/06/30 18:43:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/30 18:43:13 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
17/06/30 18:43:13 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/06/30 18:43:13 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
17/06/30 18:43:13 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
17/06/30 18:43:13 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
17/06/30 18:43:13 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/06/30 18:43:13 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/06/30 18:43:13 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM APP_INSTANCE AS t WHERE 1=0
17/06/30 18:43:13 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
17/06/30 18:43:14 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
```

**tnsnames.ora:**

```
testssl =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = IP )(PORT = 2484))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = ORACL)))
```

**sqlnet.ora:**

```
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)  
      (METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/app/Wallets/client_wallet)))
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (tcps)
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
```

Try with SQLPLUS:

```
$ sqlplus64 neon_main/bullet@testssl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Jun 30 19:23:58 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

This is working fine. But not working with JDBC.

Please point me out where am wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using the TNS Name alias, you should pass the -Doracle.net.tns_admin= explicitly.  Also, JDBC thin will not read the file sqlnet.ora.  So, these properties need to be explicitly passed as connection level properties.

Check out [SSL with JDBC whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) for more details.